# Не проходит get запрос в Postman

Tags: java, spring-boot

При тестировании spring boot приложения с помощью Postman столкнулся с ошибкой которую получаю в ответ на get запрос с pathparam: the requested resource could not be found but may be available again in the future.Не могу понять как можно это исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Уточните вопрос, потому что в таком виде как сейчас, невозможно ничего понять.

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверьте настройки веб сервера. Он должен быть настроен на HTTP-порт 8080
2. Также проверьте роутинг в вашем приложении. по URL /api/cars должен быть находиться Контроллер отвечающий за обработку этого запроса. Вероятно по введенному URL web-сервер и ваше приложение не могут найти кому передать обработку запроса. Отсюда 404 Ресурс не найден.
3. ошибка в URL